# The argument “Intent data” from onActivityResult is null

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, null

I have an Activity A and a Fragment B.

In A I have this method:

```
private void installApp(String path){
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    fileUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(path));
    i.setDataAndType(fileUri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    B.startActivityForResult(i, 101); //B has been initialized elsewhere
}
```

Which later calls this override in B:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    try{
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        //Can't d stuff with data because it's Null.
    }
    }catch (Exception e){
    //Handles the exception
    }
}
```

I've been searching for a while now and still can't figure it out why data is null. What did I miss?!

Thank you.

Comment: if B is your fragment?

Answer (score 0):

In Fragment B are you calling `startActivityForResult(new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityA.class), REQUEST_CODE)` ? (REQUEST_CODE being an int)

if so then:

In Activity A you are not starting an Activity for a result. you need to call: `finish();`

in Activity A rather than 
`startActivityForResult();`

update your code to look like:

```
private void installApp(String path){
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    fileUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(path));
    i.setDataAndType(fileUri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
    finish();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation for `ACTION_VIEW`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_VIEW) has "Output: nothing", which means that `ACTION_VIEW` implementations do not supply a result, and so using `ACTION_VIEW` with `startActivityForResult()` is pointless.

Comment: Indeed this was the problem. Thank you.